# Javascript in CakePHP view causes controller action to be called twice

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I have a cakephp controller with action and associated view. The action in the controller saves some data to the database (it creates a new record) when called. I was noticing that for some reason 2 records are created. The only difference between the 2 records is the date_created field which is different by a few seconds so I know that the second (duplicate) record is being created a few seconds after the first. I have been able to narrow the problem down to some javascript that is included in the view inside  tags. I include a .js file at the top of the view using -

```
echo $this->Html->script('https://link.to.externalSite.com/script.js', array(
  'inline' => true
));
```

When I change 'inline' => true to false then the problem disappears, only 1 record is added to the database as I expect. However I need the script set inline => true for my purposes.

The  tag in the view page is triggered when a submit button on a form is clicked as follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var myVar = new .......... ({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>
```

I am wondering if this is caused because the script is loaded from an external url? If i include the script in my webroot will I avoid this problem? I have come across questions on stackoverflow about similar issues with JS scripts causing controller actions to be called twice and they talk about issues of deeplinking, however I don't understand what to do about that.

Answer (score 2):

With inline set to true, when you view your in-browser source code how many times is the script file https://link.to.externalSite.com/script.js included? Perhaps its being added by multiple view elements?

Comment: Thanks .. When I 'view source' in safari I only see the script file included once. Incase this helps - the submit button image used in the form is also included from an external source. thanks for your response.

Comment: Is there a live page you can share with us?

Comment: Hi - no sorry, Im developing locally right now and not able to share a live page.